# Manipulating lists of rules of irregular length

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, replacement

After solving a function I get a list as a set of rules. `{{x -> 0}, {x -> 0, x -> 10.}, {x -> 0, x -> 5.}, {x -> 0, x -> 3.33333}, {x -> 0, x -> 2.5}, {x -> 0, x -> 2.}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.66667}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.42857}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.25}, {x -> 0,x -> 1.11111}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.}`. The first entry in the list has a single rule while the all other entries have 2 rules. It might be possible that some entries have 3 rules also. What I need to do is replace all the rules by its values. So the resulting list should be like `{{0},{0,10},...}`. These are like values of y. Values of x are `Range[0,1,0.1]`.

To plot them, if I had list of numbers rather than a list of rules I could first extract first list as `listy1 = y[[;;,1]]; listy2 = y[[;;,2]]; p1 = ListLinePlot[]; p2 = ListLinePlot[]; Show[p1,p2]` . This also has a issue that whenever I will run a command `list2 = y[[;;,2]]`, it will fail because the second element of first row does not exist.

Please tell how to do deal with these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rules = {{x -> 0}, {x -> 0, x -> 10.}, {x -> 0, x -> 5.}, {x -> 0, 
    x -> 3.33333}, {x -> 0, x -> 2.5}, {x -> 0, x -> 2.}, {x -> 0, 
    x -> 1.66667}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.42857}, {x -> 0, 
    x -> 1.25}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.11111}, {x -> 0, x -> 1.}};
```

You can use [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
y = Values[rules]
```

> ```
> {{0}, {0, 10.}, {0, 5.}, {0, 3.33333}, {0, 2.5}, {0, 2.}, {0, 1.66667}, 
>  {0, 1.42857}, {0, 1.25}, {0, 1.11111}, {0, 1.}}
> ```

Use `PadRight` to inject a non-numeric value (say, `Null`) on the right for rows with fewer columns than the longest row:

```
ypadded = PadRight[y, Automatic, Null]
```

> ```
>  {{0, Null}, {0, 10.}, {0, 5.}, {0, 3.33333}, {0, 2.5}, {0, 2.}, 
>   {0, 1.66667}, { 0, 1.42857}, {0, 1.25}, {0, 1.11111}, {0, 1.}}
> ```

```
listy1 = ypadded[[;;, 1];

listy2 = ypadded[[;;, 2]]; 

p1 = ListLinePlot[listy1, DataRange -> {0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]; 

p2 = ListLinePlot[listy2, DataRange -> {0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green];

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can use a single `ListLinePlot` using `Transpose @ ypadded` as input:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose @ ypadded, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also tell about the second issue?

Comment: @AQ, please see the update.

Comment: Is there a way to plot the ypadded directly rather than extracting each and every column from it and then plotting it.

Comment: @AQ, use `ListLinePlot[Transpose@ypadded, DataRange -> {0, 1}]`